# C function variable changing

Tags: c, function, variables

I have a basic code to learn function call. But I did not understand something in this code. I got confused when I compare to with my answer and expected output.
 My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int a, int b, double c){
    printf("%d \n", a);printf("%d \n", b);printf("%f \n", c);
}

int main(void){
  int i = 0, x = 7;
  float a = 2.25;

  f (x=5, x-7, a);
  printf("\n\n");

  f (x = 6, x-7, a);
  printf("\n\n");

  printf("%d %d\n",i, i++ );
  printf("%d %d\n",i, ++i );
  return 0;
}
```

At the last 2 printf statements, My answer was as:

```
0 0
1 1
```

But the output as:

```
1 0
2 2
```

Can you explain why?

Comment: The only explanation that can be given for the final two printf statements is that in terms of C this is undefined behavior. Undefined meaning that the C specification doesn't specify the order in which these things will be evaluated, so depending on the compiler, C version, rotation of the earth, etc. the output will differ.

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined behavior in C. It may vary as per the execution or many other things. *The order of evaluation of function arguments are unspecified*. You can never explain the behavior you see by any standard rule. It would have given different result when you run it in front of teacher in a different machine.

Better you write the code which avoids all these sort of ambiguity.

The example which is explicit about this from [**standard 6.5.2.2p12**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p12)

> In the function call
>
> ```
>       (*pf[f1()]) (f2(), f3() + f4())
> ```
>
> **the functions `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, and `f4` may be called in any order**. All side effects have to be
>   completed before the function pointed to by pf[f1()] is called.

Same way when you pass the arguments - their evaluation order may vary. And your example of `printf` is also another such example.

<sub>Check the slide from which you got to know about this - must be a slide one ***Undefined behavior***</sub>

Comment: What did you mean? I am newer in C language.

Comment: This code was in slides from lecture. So I want to try write and run again, but I did not understand this part of code

Comment: @fokclac.: It may vary as per system to system. This code is not supposed to be defined by C standard

Comment: @fokclac: If your teacher showed you this code and did not state very clearly that **it is bad code and should not be used**, then your teacher is not qualified to teach C. When the source code is `f(x=5, x-7, a)`, the C standard (the primary document for specifying the C language) does not say whether `x=5` is evaluated first or `x-7` is evaluated first. Worse, it says that when you both assign a value to something (`x` in this case) and use it separately (`x-7` is separate from `x=5`) in an unordered way, **all** of the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil " then your teacher is not qualified to teach C" -- or the teacher simply forgot in this particular instance. Teachers are human. It's not appropriate for you to make a blanket statement.

Comment: @nicomp: Your second comment appears to be referring to some comment of yours I do not see and some comment of mine I did not write. Regarding your first comment, a mistake is forgetting some bit of syntax or some esoteric undefined behavior. The bad code shown in the question is gross and voluminous. A qualified teacher would show it only to make the point that these constructs should never be used and to explain why. As that would be the point of the lesson, it would be impossible to forget to mention they are bad. If such code was shown without the warning, the teacher is not qualified.

Comment: @EricPostpischil.: I guess it was mine just saying that maybe it was a slide on Undefined behavior. Didn't mean to say anything more.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you explain why?

Because the compiler had calculated the arguments from right to left. It was allowed to do it either way, and it finally produced the code which did it like that. You know, it didn't want to die like Buridan's donkey ;-)

You may say that C compilers have no free will. Yes, they don't, but the generated code depends on many different things, such as compiler brand, version, command-line options etc. And C standard doesn't impose any limitations on C compilers in that particular case. So it's officially called "undefined behaviour". Just never do this.